# MS Access button to open a PDF on a server

Tags: ms-access

We are trying to create a proof of delivery database and would like a button on a form that would open a scanned pdf on our server.

In the table we have created a expression in a calculated field [Location] & [Invoice No] & [PDF] which displays the location of the file (Z:\Carriers\POD\123.pdf)

Is there a way to create a button in a form that will look at [File Location] field and open the pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, could not get them to work.

Found info about FollowHyperlink and used this

Application.FollowHyperlink "Z:\Carriers\POD" & Me.[Invoice] & ".pdf"

Does exactly what we need

Thanks everyone again for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function which will open any file, that Windows can display:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' API declarations for OpenDocumentFile.
' Documentation:
'   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea
'
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "USER32" () _
    As Long
    
' Enum for ShowWindow constants (selection).
' Documentation:
'   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
'
Public Enum SwShowCommand
    swShowNormal = 1
    swShowMinimized = 2
    swShowMaximized = 3
End Enum
   
' Open a document file using its default viewer application.
' Optionally, the document can be opened minimised or maximised.
'
' Returns True if success, False if not.
' Will not raise an error if the path or file is not found.
'
' 2022-03-12. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function OpenDocumentFile( _
    ByVal File As String, _
    Optional ByVal ShowCommand As SwShowCommand = swShowNormal) _
    As Boolean

    Const OperationOpen     As String = "open"
    Const MinimumSuccess    As Long = 32
    ' Shall not have a value for opening a document.
    Const Parameters        As String = ""
    
    Dim Handle      As Long
    Dim Directory   As String
    Dim Instance    As Long
    Dim Success     As Boolean
    
    Handle = GetDesktopWindow
    Directory = Environ("Temp")

    Instance = ShellExecute(Handle, OperationOpen, File, Parameters, Directory, ShowCommand)
    ' If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater than MinimumSuccess.
    Success = (Instance > MinimumSuccess)
    
    OpenDocumentFile = Success

End Function
```

Comment: @KJ: It probably is, but it has worked well for us and, with so much else to do, it has settled as the method.